# Cannot update redux store from reducer

Tags: ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux, immutable.js

I cannot seem to update the redux store from a reducer. The state is an [immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Record) record which is pretty printed in the image.

This reducer runs:

```
const searchResultsMapRegion = (state = vepo, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'UPDATE_SEARCH_PAGE_RESULTS_PAGE_MAP_REGION': {
      console.log(state.toJS())
      const newState = state.set('some', 555)
      console.log(newState.toJS())
      return newState
    }
    default:
      return state
  }
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  product: product,
  searchResultsMapRegion: searchResultsMapRegion
})

export const rootEpic = combineEpics(
  fetchCategoriesEpic,
  getUserPositionEpic,
  getUserLocationEpic,
  getUserLocationFulfilledEpic
)

export const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  vepo,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(createEpicMiddleware(rootEpic)))
)
```

I have other reducers that act on the `product` part of the state and they work fine. Why can't I act on the `some` part of the state as shown in the question?

console.log of `state` at the top of the reducer:

[image]

console.log of `newState` inside the reducer
[image]

console.log of `state` once the reducer has finished running:

[image]

Comment: What is the value of `state`? What does `state.set` do and return?

Comment: @FelixKling `state` is an [immutable js record](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Record). I have console logged it with the `toJS()` function to pretty print it. `.set()` returns a new copy of the record with the modified property.

Comment: Are you using the built in `combineReducers` or the one for [`redux-immutable`](https://github.com/gajus/redux-immutable)? See [the Redux docs](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/beyond-combinereducers#using-slice-reducers-with-immutable-js-objects) for more details.

Comment: @MichaelPeyper I have resolved this now. My initial state of the redux store had property names that differed from the properties entered into `combineReducers`. Is it not even necessary to provide the initial state to `createStore()`? I have been setting up the initial state with falsey values.

Comment: @MichaelPeyper I see now it is optional to set up the initial state.

Answer (score 0):

Recheck case type. Does that refer to correct case value? Also,vepo needs to be removed from createStore.

```
export const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  vepo,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(createEpicMiddleware(rootEpic)))
)
```

Comment: The case type is correct. Maybe I misunderstand you, but `vepo` is the state of the whole app which needs to go inside `createStore`, and you have left it inside it in your answer.

Comment: rootReducer will have all the data and that only needs to be passed to createstore.